# Does variation of parameters always work?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the differential equation $y'-2y=e^x$.
I solved the homogenous differential equation and I got that $y_0(x)=e^{2x}\cdot c$, where $c$ is a real constant.
Now I want to apply variation of parameters. So, $y_p=c(x)\cdot e^{2x}$ and $y'_p=c'(x)\cdot e^{2x}+2\cdot c(x)e^{2x}$ and if I plug it into my equation I get that $c'(x)\cdot e^{2x}=e^x$, so $c'(x)=e^{-x}$ and $c(x)=-e^{-x}$. But this doesn't verify my equation. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do not forget $c(x)=-e^{-x}+K$

Answer (score 1):

The particular solution is not $c(x)$ but $y_p = e^{2x}c(x) = -e^{x}$, which verifies the equation.

Comment: Oh, right, I am so dumb, I forgot to do the multiplication, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution of the linear ODE $$y'-2y=e^x \implies y=e^{2x}\int e^{-2x} e^x dx+C e^{2x} \implies y(x)=-e^{x}+Ce^{2x}$$

The solution of homogeneous part is $y=P e^{2x}$. Let us vary $P$ as $P(x)$  and put in $y'-2y=e^{x}$ to get $$P'=e^{-x} \implies P(x)=-e^{-x} +D \implies y(x)=-e^{x}+De^{2x}.$$
The same as above.